# Concurrent AJAX calls in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How can we `trigger` concurrent requests in `JMeter`...

I am not talking about the non -html elements (where we have a provision in jmeter to download them concurrently).

I have few AJAX calls to be downloaded concurrently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per JMeter 3.0 there is no suitable Test Elements, you will need to:

- go for [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) + [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) and [Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/) (which are parts of JMeter anyway)
- or develop your custom sampler to overcome JMeter thread group limitation and kick off extra threads to execute AJAX calls.

Example JSR223 Sampler Code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors; // necessary imports


List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize array of URLs
Collections.addAll(urls,args); // read URLs from "Parameters" input and add them to array
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(urls.size()); // initialize pool of Future Tasks with number of threads equal to size of URLs provided
for (String url : urls) { // for each URL from list
   final String currentURL = url;
   pool.submit(new Runnable() { // Sumbit a new thread which will execute GET request

       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Use Apache Commons HTTPClient to perform GET request
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(currentURL);
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
   });
}
pool.shutdown(); // shut down thread pool
```

More details: [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a query on this, this will create new threads and that will not disturb my total thread count? Suppose I am executing a test with 50 users (threads), now if i create a pool of 10 threads, the burden on server will increase.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how AJAX requests work, moreover, this is also how JMeter works when it downloads embedded resources using parallel thread pool. For more tips on making your JMeter test more realistic check out [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide

Comment: @DmitriT - Is there a way to get the body of the response? because "response.getEntity();" gives you only the response headers.